# Playing music in onFocusChangeListner()

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I am Trying to Play/pause music when my custom View looses focus(when LockScreen Button is Pressed) i tried to implement onFocusChangeListner(), This code is working fine when activity gets created i.e music is played but when user presses lockScreen button and returns to app later music is not played. Can any body help me or tell me whats i am missing Api level is 8-16. Thanx in advance

public class StartGameActivity extends BaseActivity implements
        OnFocusChangeListener {
    private PuzzleView puzzleview;

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // custom View for activity set to focusable(true), & focusable
    // inTouchmode(true)
    puzzleview = new PuzzleView(this);
    puzzleview.setOnFocusChangeListener(this);
    setContentView(puzzleview);
}

protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

}

    protected void onPause(){
            super.onPause();
            StopMusic();
    }


@Override
public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
    if (hasFocus) {
        Initialize_Music_Player():
    }
    if (!hasFocus) {
        StopMusic();
    }
}
```

}